# Physics, a wheel on an inclined surface

Tags: unity-game-engine, physics

I want to program some part of physics. I have a wheel and an inclined surface. When the wheel dropped on the surface it should go along that surface. 
I know how to calculate force and direction of movement after the wheel is dropped on the surface, but how this wheel should behave after that?

Here is my current code

```
using UnityEngine;

public class MyPhysics : MonoBehaviour
{

public LayerMask lMask;
public Rigidbody2D ball;
public CircleCollider2D circle;
public Vector2 gravity;
public Vector2 velocity;
public float mass = 1;
public Vector2 a;
public bool simulate = true;

private Vector2 weight;
private float radius;


// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    radius = ball.transform.localScale.x * circle.radius;
    weight = mass * gravity;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (simulate)
        DoAllShit();
}

void DoAllShit()
{
    a += (gravity * Time.deltaTime);
    velocity = (velocity + a);

    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(ball.position, velocity.normalized, velocity.magnitude + radius, lMask);
    if (hit)
    {
        float angle = Vector2.Angle(hit.normal, velocity) - 90;
        // Debug.Log("angle: " + angle);
        float magnitude = velocity.magnitude * Mathf.Cos(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle);
        // Debug.Log("magnitude of velocity: " + velocity.magnitude + "  magnitude of cos: " + magnitude);
        Vector2 rotatedVector = GetPerp(hit.normal, velocity);
        Vector2 newVector = magnitude * rotatedVector;
        Debug.DrawLine(hit.point, hit.point + rotatedVector, Color.blue, float.MaxValue);
        Debug.Log("normal: " + hit.normal + "  rotated vector: " + rotatedVector + " velocity: " + velocity);
        Debug.DrawLine(hit.point + hit.normal * 0.1f, hit.point + hit.normal * 0.1f + newVector, Color.red, float.MaxValue);
        velocity = newVector;
        ball.position = velocity + (hit.normal * radius + hit.point);
        //simulate = false;
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.DrawLine(ball.position, ball.position + velocity.normalized * (velocity.magnitude + radius), Color.green, float.MaxValue);
        ball.position += (velocity);
    }
}

Vector2 GetPerp(Vector2 normal, Vector2 velocity)
{
    Vector2 perp;
    if (velocity.y <= 0)
    {
        normal.y *= -1;
    }
    else
    {
        normal.x *= -1;
    }
    perp.x = normal.y;
    perp.y = normal.x;

    return perp;
}
```

}

Comment: Follow your basic laws. You have the force information and you have the information on the angle of the incline so you can also calculate the velocity of the wheel over time. You can determine the direction of motion also from this. You know that unless an outside force acts on the object it will continue to move. You need to determine if your system is ideal or will be affected by friction.

Comment: it has no friction right now. The main problem for now is that I cast the ray in direction of the velocity, from the center of object, and if the surface's angle changes - the object will be drowned in the surface because that ray don't hit any surface due to his direction and position

Comment: You should be calculating the object's position, which adjusts for the height of the object, at each interval of time. If you do so you shouldn't have an issue  just because the surface angle changes. At each instant you should know where your surface is as it relates to your object.

Comment: okay, it seems like I have to cast an additional ray to figure out where the surface is, thanks